# Error with optional generic mapper function

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a function that takes an array of objects, and maps over them. The function has 2 possible signatures:

1. Data and Key Getter:

   ```
   type KeyMapOnly<T> = (data: T[], keyGetter: (itm: T) => string) => T[]
   ```
2. Data, Key Getter, and Value Getter

   ```
   type KeyAndValue<T, U> = (
     data: T[],
     keyGetter: (itm: T) => string,
     valueGetter: (itm: T) => U
   ) => Record<string, U>
   ```

However when I try to put these 2 together, I am getting errors. What am I doing wrong here?

```
type KeyGetter<T> = (itm: T) => string                                                                          
type ValueGetter<T, U> = (itm: T) => U                                                                     
                                                                                                                      
const identity = <T>(itm: T): T => itm                                    
                                                                                                         
type IndexFunc = {                                                                                   
  <T>(arr: T[], keyGetter: KeyGetter<T>): Record<string, T>                                              
  <T, U>(                                                                 
    arr: T[],                                                                                                 
    keyGetter: KeyGetter<T>,                                              
    valueGetter: ValueGetter<T, U>                                                                       
  ): Record<string, U>                                                    
}                                                                  
                                                                                     
export const buildIndex: IndexFunc = (                                                            
  arr,                                                                                                    
  keyGetter,                                                                                      
  valueGetter = identity                                                       
) => {                                                                    
  const result = {} as any                                                                                   
                                                                               
  for (const itm of arr) {                                                
    result[keyGetter(itm)] = valueGetter(itm)                                                                  
  }                                                                            
                                                                          
  return result                                                                           
}
```

With this configuration, I am getting the following errors:

```
Parameter 'arr' implicitly has an 'any' type. 
Parameter 'keyGetter' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

These two parameters are both present in **both** of the function overloads, so I am confused how these could possibly have type any.

- `data` is always of type `T[]`
- `keyGetter` is always of type `(itm: T) => string`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: ① It's not that you're doing anything *wrong* but you've hit a design limitation of TS as per [ms/TS#38625](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38625) ② You say "override" but the right term here is "overload" (those are different), you might want to [edit]. ③ If you want to refactor you could possibly combine the call signatures like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3VDLN). ⊛ Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if so, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz re: overload - yes, that's what I meant. Updating now.

Comment: What about the other parts of my comment? Do they fully address the question (so I should write up an actual answer) or am I missing something (and if so, what)?

Comment: I think this does, it's unfortunate there's not a cleaner solution, but this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is considered a design limitation of TypeScript, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#38625](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38625). Currently function parameters are not [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) by [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) function types, and so unless you manually [annotate the parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations), they will be implicitly typed as `any` and you'll get a warning (assuming [the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noImplicitAny) is enabled).

So your choices are to either manually annotate things, which requires a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function implementation:

```
export const buildIndex: IndexFunc = <T,>(
    arr: T[],
    keyGetter: KeyGetter<T>,
    valueGetter = identity
) => {
    const result = {} as any

    for (const itm of arr) {
        result[keyGetter(itm)] = valueGetter(itm)
    }

    return result
}
```

or to abandon overloads in favor of some combined call signature like

```
type IndexFunc = {
    <T, U = T>(
        arr: T[],
        keyGetter: KeyGetter<T>,
        valueGetter?: ValueGetter<T, U>
    ): Record<string, U>
}

export const buildIndex: IndexFunc = (
    arr,
    keyGetter,
    valueGetter = identity as any // <-- need this
) => {
    const result = {} as any

    for (const itm of arr) {
        result[keyGetter(itm)] = valueGetter(itm)
    }

    return result
}
```

(Note that you need an additional [assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that `identity` is an appropriate default, since users can, but probably won't, do something like `buildIndex<number, boolean>([1, 2, 3], (n) => "k" + n)`.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)